# Mysql SQL DELETE JOIN in particular order (Due to constraints)

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, sql-delete

Is it possible to delete from different tables in particular order?

I need to delete

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 on t2.id =t1.t2_id
LEFT JOIN T3 on t3.id =t1.t3_id
```

But only in this order (`t1>t2>t3`) because of constraints in databases.
Sometimes it seems the order is not followed.

Comment: Why don't you declare `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the foreign key constraints? Then you just delete in T1 and it will automatically delete the related T2 and T3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can temporary disable foreign keys checks

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DELETE t1, t2, t3
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 on t2.id =t1.t2_id
LEFT JOIN T3 on t3.id =t1.t3_id

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```